# How to get a selection of an observable collection (silverlight) given the first index and index of last element

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I want to basically get a selection of items from a collection and put it in another collection given the index of the first and last element.
so say we have an observable collection of 100 object, i only want from 0 to 50 and want to put that in another collection how do i do that?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

```
int firstElIndex = 4;
int lastElIndex = 20;

var coll = new ObservableCollection<int>(Enumerable.Range(0,30));
List<int> result = coll.Skip(firstElIndex - 1).
     Take(lastElIndex - firstElIndex + 1).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

See this method [List.GetRange Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/21k0e39c.aspx) .

```
int startIndex = 0;
int endIndex = 50;
// assuming endIndex is greater than startIndex
int count = endIndex - startIndex; 
var requiredRangeOfElements = yourCollection.ToList().GetRange(startIndex, count)
```

Comment: hi there, its not a list its an ObservableCollection<objects> so it doesnt have a getrange method